# Creating .MDF With SQL 2008 EXPRESS/ Visual Web Developer 2008

Tags: sql, visual-web-developer, mdf

I am trying to create a login function with SQL server 2008 express and Visual Web Developer 2008 Express.
I tried Using a Login status and Login controll / Running the page without debugging and then attempting to login. I was told this would create a ASPNETDB.MDF. file; Instead it gave me an error. I then attempted to create a database in my AppData section of Visual web developer and it gave me this error:

> connections to sql server files (.mdf) Require sql server 2005 to function properly. please verify the installation of the component or download from (url).

I have sql 2008 express installed and (to my knowledge) Need ASPNETDB.MDF to create a login system on my site. Am i going to have to downgrade my sql server in order to get a functioning login on my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASPNETDB.MDF is the default database for using the ASP.NET Application Services, which includes profiles, roles, membership and more. You can use the supplied membership providers that are included with the .NET Framework, or you can implement your own providers.

You do not have to downgrade SQL Server in order to get a functioning login on your site. To resolve the error message, verify that SQL Server express edition is properly installed and is currently running on the system. You can use SQL Server Configuration Manager to check and start the SQL instances that are installed on the system.

If the SQL Server Express instance is running, check if Visual Studio is pointing to the correct SQL instance. You can do this by navigating to Data connections under Tools -> Options in Visual Studio IDE.

Links:

1. [Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009225)
2. [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: My Default instance was incorrect; Now i can manually create databases (thank you!) I am still receiving this error : (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)  and  im unable to auto-create the DB file that has pre-populated member info (ideal for me since im a novice) Could it be that .net is trying to use a "roll" or account that doesnt have read / write capabilitys to the server?

Comment: Alfredo, this blog talks about the error: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

Comment: Alfredo, please mark my answer as correct if my reply provided the answer to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: I have done much research for the last 2 days and realized that many people have had this same problem ive tried a number of things to fix it however no luck; I will continue to look around till i am able to get it working and post back with my results. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have follow up inquiries, consider asking a new question on Stack Overflow. The community is very helpful.

Comment: Tarzan i was able to get it working :D - Reinstalled sql and gave it an instance name / mixed login as oposed to windows authentication. Thanks again.  In Case Any one is reading this due to having a similar problem; the above listed links should get the job done if your still having problems this might help its how i solved my problem :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074273/unable-to-auto-create-aspnetdb-mdf-visual-web-developer-express-2008-sql-exp/13096096#13096096